# Why did my answer only receive half of the 50 bounty?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

I spent some time on this for a 50 bounty, but it only got 25?

[MacOS highlight individual words as they are spoken, as iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347831/macos-highlight-individual-words-as-they-are-spoken-as-ios/349355#349355)

Comment: It's very frustrating when you spend a significant amount of time researching and formatting an answer and then the OP doesn't even bother to return to the question to accept the answer.  I keep track of the user name to help me determine if I'll answer their questions again.

Comment: @fsb I don't mind too much really, the information may help others in future

Comment: @fsb What if the OP did return, but did not think any answers deserved the bounty?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy We'll never know if they did or not.  The OP should leave a comment or something to indicate that.  They started the bounty with the understanding of how they work; they can clearly see the amount of effort put into the answer(s).  To not even acknowledge the work others did to help someone solve a problem is not only frustrating but rude on the OPs part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be the case that the bounty starter did not award the +50 bounty. But your answer has two upvotes nonetheless.

As [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) explains:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted **answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty** amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Answer (score 3):

From the help center:

If [the person who placed the bounty] do[es] not award [the] bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.